# Need python script for vulnerability assessment?

Tags: security, web-server, python

How to scan my server remotely? I want to scan a website, so my server, and gathered information related to webserver and other software associated info. I got one named blindelephant . But it is not serving my purpose.

**Webserver related info:** Which server serving the app? what is the version? etc

**software associated info:** What are the software or tool used by the application. What are their version?

I am trying to build a vulnerability assessment tool for that i need to know the web server and software packages used to run a website or web application.

Say: A script will take google.com and find the web server info(which @ABS has almost answered) and external software packages dependencies to run Google.com.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Vulnerability assessment is something best left to the experts honestly. You should probably be looking for a service or website to do this. Unless you have time to keep up with the constantly evolving threats on the Internet your tool will be outdated before it's finished.

Comment: I'm not sure if this might fit better on Security.SE or StackOverflow.  Could you clarify whether you are writing a scanning tool or looking for one to use on your own site?

Comment: I am thinking of writing my own.

Comment: If you have to ask how, you'll probably struggle but don't let us stop you then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already are vulnerability assessment frameworks available, like Nessus and SAINT. You would get another host outside your network, like from a home connection or using Amazon's EC2 service, install the tools, and run them against your own website.

EDIT - if you're going to write your own, look at open source software to tell you how they do it, like using OS fingerprinting in NMap and the plugins for Nessus/SAINT type applications. Then read books on reverse-engineering malware and study how they work to do your own original take on it. Malware is an ever-changing field and most conventional techniques are well documented in existing auditing frameworks (some of them are used by blackhats to create more script-kiddie tools, if that tells you anything).

This all depends on whether you're doing it just to do it, or if you're trying to make a genuinely useful program/service. If you're doing it on your own for fun, more power to you. If you just decided one day to do this as a service/application to sell, you might want to reconsider. Security isn't easy, and there is a certain amount of trust placed in tools used by people.

Comment: I would definitely add [W3AF](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/) to that list.  It's open source and already written in Python.